# Typing in Terminal underlines characters, adds accented characters

Tags: debian, gnome-terminal, input-method

Whenever I type in Terminal now (it never happened before, I must've enabled it by accident), I get an option to enter an accented character. I want to turn this off.

It looks like this (except with `d` underlined rather than bold):

```
$ git ad
```

Then when I type d again, it makes it:

```
$ git ađ
```

This is really annoying behavior. How do I turn off this autocomplete thing?

Comment: Does this behaviour continue if you close the terminal (log out) and open a new one? Or is that not possible?

Comment: I just checked. The behavior stops if I exit the Terminal and open a new one. I suppose I could just kill that Terminal, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Sure but I assume the "real" answer is complicated. This effect can be caused by key bindings in the shell (see the section `READLINE` in `man bash` if you use bash) or by the desktop environment (probably not the case here because that would affect all terminals) or by the terminal emulator. Some terminal problems can be solved with the command `reset` but I guess that would not help with such special chars.

Comment: This is called an input method. I don't know where you might have enabled it, but dig in the terminal or system configuration (probably in the keyboard configuration) and you should be able to find it. Is this the Gnome terminal application?

Comment: Yes it's gnome-terminal.